# cucumber_report.json file does not overwrite to get the latest test steps

Tags: typescript, protractor, cucumber, appium

Under reports/html folder within my framework, the cucumber_reporter.json file does not overwrite. It should overwrite cucumber_reporter.json so that any new test or updated test in .feature file will be processed from json to html report

I assume its because of the cucumberOpts option, so I changed few things within that like changing the 
format:[ "json:./reports/json/cucumber_report.json ] option 
this will create a new report file(cucumber_report.58053.json) in reports/html with the timestamp always, But if I not include the format option and comment it out and run the test, it will not create the new file

My config.ts

```
import {Config} from 'protractor';
import * as tsNode from 'ts-node';
import { Reporter } from "../support/reporter";
const jsonReports = process.cwd() + "/reports/json";

export let config: Config = {

    specs: [
        '../../features/*.feature'
    ],
    onPrepare: () => {
         Reporter.createDirectory(jsonReports);
        tsNode.register({
            project: './tsconfig.json'
        });
    },
    framework: 'custom',
    frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
    cucumberOpts: {
        compiler: "ts:ts-node/register",
        glue : [ "steps" ],
        plugin: [
            "com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:",
            "rerun:target/rerun.txt",
        ],
        format: [
        "json:./reports/json/cucumber_report.json",
        ],
        require: ['supports/timeout.js', '../../stepdefinitions/*.ts'],
        tags: "@firstPurchasePopup",
    },
    onComplete: () => {
        Reporter.createHTMLReport();
    },
};
```

I am expecting the cucumber_report.json file to be created every time we run the test and not create it with a new timestamp file.
Also, the Html (cucumber_reporter.html) to have an updated report in line with the test steps.

If I change the test steps (cucumber .feature file) and run the test the report does not gets updated with the latest test steps but will have the older test still.

===**More info**========
if I comment the line of the format in the below code, the cucumber_report.json file will not be created

```
cucumberOpts: {
compiler: "ts:ts-node/register",
glue : [ "steps" ],
format: [
"json:./reports/json/cucumber_report.json",
],
```

If I leave as it is without comment, it will create that file with a timestamp like cucumber_report.8561.json", and it keeps creating like that for each run, which I feel is not correct. It should not create that timestamp why or how is it creating I am not sure. That where I need help. Since it creates a new file(.json file) with that timestamp everytime, the .html report trys to read from the cucumber_report.json file which does not exists. And making that the .html reprot will not be generated

Comment: hi Lokesh, were you able to get a solution to this problem.... I'm facing the same problem in my project. I too need to overwrite the cucumber json report every time so that based on the report, have to call an api request etc. Please reply if you got any solution for the question... It will be very much helpful.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are using 'multiCapabilities'. If you test only one browser you can use 'capabilities', then there is no timestamp.